# If $\hat{D}$ minimizes trace over all $D+ B \succeq 0$, then is $\hat{D}_{ii} \leq \sum_{j} |B_{ij}|$ for each $i$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, semidefinite-programming

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ real matrix and let $B$ be the block bipartite matrix

$$B = \begin{bmatrix} 0&A \\
 A^{T}&0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Let $\hat{D}$ be a solution to the SDP that minimizes $tr(D)$ over all diagonal matrices $D$ such that $B + D \succeq 0$.

Numerically, I wrote a program for various random $A$ and I keep getting that the diagonal entry is less than or equal to the absolute value sum of the corresponding row of $B$, that is $\hat{D}_{ii} \leq \sum_{j} |B_{ij}|$ for each $i$.

**I was wondering if there was a way to prove this?**

I guess by assumption, $\hat{D} - \epsilon{e_{i}e_{i}}^{T}$ is not positive definite for any $i$ and $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: No. If $i$-th row of $A$ is zero, your condition $D_{ii} \le \sum_j |A_{ij}|$ (or do you mean something different?) forces $D_{ii}=0$, but this isn't good if $i$-th column of $A$ isn't zero.

Comment: The $ith$ column of $A$ corresponds I think to the $M+i$ th row of $B$?